# I want to slideUp the current content then slideDown the clicked content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the current content to slideUp and then slideDown the clicked content and I am stumped on why the code I have won't work. It just slides down the text . content. Any help much appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('nav ul a').click(function(){    
        var newTopicText = $(this).html();            
        $('#topic').fadeOut(function () {     
            $('#topic').text(newTopicText).fadeIn();      
            $(".contentContainer").slideUp(1500, function() {    
                $(".contentContainer").html('.content');
            }).slideDown(1500);      
         });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do .html('.content'), you're telling jQuery to literally make ".content" the innerHTML of the container (ex.: div or span with class .contentContainer).

It's a little unclear what content you are trying to place in .contentContainer, but assuming it is the html of the first tag with the class ".content", you could use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('nav ul a').click(function(){    
    var newTopicText = $(this).html();            
    $('#topic').fadeOut(function () {     
        $('#topic').text(newTopicText).fadeIn();      
        $(".contentContainer").slideUp(1500, function() {    
            // Change this line...
            $(".contentContainer").html($('.content').html());
        }).slideDown(1500);
     });
   });
});
```

Edit: Updated to make it take the content of the first tag with the class ".content".

http://jsfiddle.net/nn0x6da8/2/